# AWS Pipeline - Broken build

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codepipeline

My code pipeline stopped working and the error message is:

```
yarn run v1.21.1
$ react-app-rewired build
Creating an optimized production build...

<--- Last few GCs --->

[23:0x55e3d7ad8700]   188895 ms: Mark-sweep 1824.5 (1875.9) -> 1823.0 (1883.6) MB, 1725.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.109, current mu = 0.013) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[23:0x55e3d7ad8700]   191161 ms: Mark-sweep 1831.3 (1884.2) -> 1829.9 (1889.8) MB, 2253.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.052, current mu = 0.006) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x55e3d5b70342]
Security context: 0x0be28ab9a299 <JSObject>
    1: addMappingWithCode [0x396c722b2119] [/app/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-node.js:~150] [pc=0xd1b26fc691d](this=0x304f7c5044c1 <JSGlobal Object>,0x32d3c4a6d401 <Object map = 0x12d61490c7a9>,0x069a17fc0ae1 <String[18]:               var >)
    2: /* anonymous */ [0x2863e0300269] [/app/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-node.js:~86] [pc=0xd1b26fc4673...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Writing Node.js report to file: report.20210409.212950.23.0.001.json
Node.js report completed
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
The command '/bin/sh -c yarn run build' returned a non-zero code: 1

[Container] 2021/04/09 21:29:51 Command did not exit successfully docker build -f Dockerfile-prod -t $REPOSITORY_URI:$BRANCH --build-arg API_URL=$API_URL --build-arg PORTAL_TOKEN=$PORTAL_TOKEN --build-arg REACT_ENV=$REACT_ENV . exit status 1
[Container] 2021/04/09 21:29:51 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2021/04/09 21:29:51 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker build -f Dockerfile-prod -t $REPOSITORY_URI:$BRANCH --build-arg API_URL=$API_URL --build-arg PORTAL_TOKEN=$PORTAL_TOKEN --build-arg REACT_ENV=$REACT_ENV .. Reason: exit status 1
[Container] 2021/04/09 21:29:51 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2021/04/09 21:29:51 Running command bash -c "if [ /"$CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING/" == /"0/" ]; then exit 1; fi"

[Container] 2021/04/09 21:29:51 Command did not exit successfully bash -c "if [ /"$CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING/" == /"0/" ]; then exit 1; fi" exit status 1
[Container] 2021/04/09 21:29:51 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2021/04/09 21:29:51 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: bash -c "if [ /"$CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING/" == /"0/" ]; then exit 1; fi". Reason: exit status 1
[Container] 2021/04/09 21:29:51 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/04/09 21:29:51 Phase context status code:  Message: yarn run v1.21.1
$ react-app-rewired build
Creating an optimized production build...

<--- Last few GCs --->

[23:0x55e3d7ad8700]   188895 ms: Mark-sweep 1824.5 (1875.9) -> 1823.0 (1883.6) MB, 1725.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.109, current mu = 0.013) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[23:0x55e3d7ad8700]   191161 ms: Mark-sweep 1831.3 (1884.2) -> 1829.9 (1889.8) MB, 2253.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.052, current mu = 0.006) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x55e3d5b70342]
Security context: 0x0be28ab9a299 <JSObject>
    1: addMappingWithCode [0x396c722b2119] [/app/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-node.js:~150] [pc=0xd1b26fc691d](this=0x304f7c5044c1 <JSGlobal Object>,0x32d3c4a6d401 <Object map = 0x12d61490c7a9>,0x069a17fc0ae1 <String[18]:               var >)
    2: /* anonymous */ [0x2863e0300269] [/app/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-node.js:~86] [pc=0xd1b26fc4673...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Writing Node.js report to file: report.20210409.212950.23.0.001.json
Node.js report completed
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
The command '/bin/sh -c yarn run build' returned a non-zero code: 1

[Container] 2021/04/09 21:29:51 Command did not exit successfully docker build -f Dockerfile-prod -t $REPOSITORY_URI:$BRANCH --build-arg API_URL=$API_URL --build-arg PORTAL_TOKEN=$PORTAL_TOKEN --build-arg REACT_ENV=$REACT_ENV . exit status 1
[Container] 2021/04/09 21:29:51 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2021/04/09 21:29:51 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker build -f Dockerfile-prod -t $REPOSITORY_URI:$BRANCH --build-arg API_URL=$API_URL --build-arg PORTAL_TOKEN=$PORTAL_TOKEN --build-arg REACT_ENV=$REACT_ENV .. Reason: exit status 1
[Container] 2021/04/09 21:29:51 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2021/04/09 21:29:51 Running command bash -c "if [ /"$CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING/" == /"0/" ]; then exit 1; fi"

[Container] 2021/04/09 21:29:51 Command did not exit successfully bash -c "if [ /"$CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING/" == /"0/" ]; then exit 1; fi" exit status 1
[Container] 2021/04/09 21:29:51 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2021/04/09 21:29:51 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: bash -c "if [ /"$CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING/" == /"0/" ]; then exit 1; fi". Reason: exit status 1
[Container] 2021/04/09 21:29:51 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/04/09 21:29:51 Phase context status code:  Message:
```

The line

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

suggests a memory issue.

So, on AWS I tried:
Developer Tools -> CodeBuild -> Build projects -> Edit -> Environment -> Additional Configuration and first increased the compute section from 3 GB memory, 2 vCPUs to 7 GB memory, 4 vCPUs and then from 7 GB memory, 4 vCPUs to 15 GB memory, 8 vCPUs.

Also, I tried adding to the package.json file something like the following and some variations of it:

```
"start": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 start",
"build": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=512 && react-app-rewired build",
```

My last try was adding

```
- export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192”
```

To the command section to the buildspec.yml file.

Here is the scripts part of my package.json file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

And here is my buildspec.xml file.

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      docker: 18
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...      
      - aws --version
      - docker login --username ******  --password ‘******’
      - $(aws ecr get-login --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --no-include-email)
      - export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192”
  build:
    commands:
      - docker build -f Dockerfile-prod -t $REPOSITORY_URI:$BRANCH --build-arg API_URL=$API_URL --build-arg PORTAL_TOKEN=$PORTAL_TOKEN --build-arg REACT_ENV=$REACT_ENV .
      - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:$BRANCH $REPOSITORY_URI:$CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION
  post_build:
    commands:
      - bash -c "if [ /"$CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING/" == /"0/" ]; then exit 1; fi"
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$BRANCH
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION
      - echo Writing image definitions file...
      - printf "[{\"name\":\"$TASK_DEFINITION-Instance\",\"imageUri\":\"%s\"}]" $REPOSITORY_URI:$CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION > imagedefinitions.json
artifacts:
  files: imagedefinitions.json
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is my buildspecs file where I had fixed the issue which I made in the light of your question and the details you put there

```
version: 0.2

env:
  variables:
    NODE_ENV: 'development'

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 12
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Deploy website
  build:
    commands:
      - rm -rf .git
      - yarn install
      - NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"
      - yarn build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo 'Invalidating distribuition cache'
      - aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id my_id --paths "/*"
```